# How I can change size fa fa-instagram (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Hello how I can change size fa fa-instagram on wordpress website?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write normal CSS as you do for other class

```
.fa-instagram{
    font-size:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code `<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-10x"></i>`

If you cant edit the code, then use CSS 
`.fa.fa-instagram { font-size: 10em; }`